# Plot a plane in R: PCA

Tags: r, plot, 3d, plane

I'm working with a PCA problem where I have 3 variables and I reduce them to 2 by doing PCA. I've already plot all the points in 3D using scatter3D. My question is, how can I plot the plane determined by two vectors (the first two eigenvectors of the sampled covariance matrix) in R?

This is what I have so far

```
library(plot3D)
X <- matrix(c(55, 75, 110,
          47, 69, 108,
          42, 71, 110,
          48, 74, 114,
          47, 75, 114,
          52, 73, 104,
          49, 72, 106,
          44, 67, 107,
          52, 73, 108,
          45, 73, 111,
          50, 80, 117,
          50, 71, 110,
          48, 75, 114,
          51, 73, 106,
          44, 66, 102,
          42, 71, 112,
          50, 68, 107,
          48, 70, 108,
          51, 72, 108,
          52, 73, 109,
          49, 72, 112,
          49, 73, 108,
          46, 70, 105,
          39, 66, 100,
          50, 76, 108,
          52, 71, 108,
          56, 75, 108,
          53, 70, 112,
          53, 72, 110,
          49, 74, 113,
          51, 72, 109,
          55, 74, 110,
          56, 75, 110,
          62, 79, 118,
          58, 77, 115,
          50, 71, 105,
          52, 67, 104,
          52, 73, 107,
          56, 73, 106,
          55, 78, 118,
          53, 68, 103), ncol = 3,nrow = 41,byrow = TRUE)
S <- cov(X)
Gamma <- eigen(S)$vectors
scatter3D(X[,1], X[,2], X[,3], pch = 18, bty = "u", colkey = FALSE, 
      main ="bty= 'u'", col.panel ="gray", expand =0.4, 
      col.grid = "white",ticktype = "detailed",
      phi = 25,theta = 45)
pc <- scale(X,center=TRUE,scale=FALSE) %*% Gamma[,c(1,2)]
```

Now I would like to plot the plane using scatter3D

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will do. Using the `iris` data. It uses `scatter3d` in package `car` which can add a regression surface to a 3d plot:

```
library(car)
data(iris)
iris.pr <- prcomp(iris[, 1:3], scale.=TRUE)
# Draw 3d plot with surface and color points by species
scatter3d(PC3~PC1+PC2, iris.pr$x, point.col=c(rep(2, 50), rep(3, 50), rep(4, 50)))
```

This plots a regression surface predicting PC3 from PC1 and PC2. By definition the correlation between any two principal components is zero so the surface should be PC3=0 for any values of PC1 and PC2, but I don't see a way to produce exactly that surface. It is pretty close though.

[image: 3d plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've edited my question, could you please take a look? I'm doing pca "by hand" and in this example I don't have distintic groups

Comment: Your results exactly match `prcomp(X)`, but the problem is that your plane defined by `pc` is not defined in the third dimension so there is no obvious place to put it in the 3d scatterplot except perhaps at the mean value for the vertical axis. Secondly the plane is defined by centered values (value - mean) so it does not fit anywhere in your 3D space. You could use `scale` with the column means to put it back into the same scale as your 3D plot.

Comment: I missed the `surf=` argument in `scatter3D()` originally, but to use it you need to have values for the third dimension.